# Multiplicative linear maps from $C^{n}[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am sure the following result is true. I am not sure how to prove it. Let $C^{n}[0,1]$ denote the space of n-times continuously differentiable maps from [0,1] into $\mathbb{C}$. Are all linear multiplicative maps $\phi : C^{n}[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the form $\phi(f) = f(c)$ where $c \in [0,1]$.

Edit:

I think every element of $C^n[0,1]$ is generated by the function $h : C^n[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as $h(t) = t$ as $ 0 \leq t \leq 1$ generates $C^n[0,1]$. If someone know why this is true or if this is true, then that would be nice.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try again.

Comment: @zhw. I have adjusted the question.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.

Comment: @zhw. I have also included little more details as well.

Comment: How about $\phi(f)=0$ for all $f$?

Comment: @lhf here t ranges between [0,1].